# Use NotePad++ & regex to concatenate all instances of a match with a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a bunch of `.php` files with incomplete references.

For instance: `<a href="dishItem.php">`.

I'm trying to use the NotePad++ Find and replace feature to find all the `.php` instances and concatenate a string in front of the match. So, after finding the previous example it would concatenate it with `http://Example.com/` like: `<a href="http://Example.com/dishItem.php">`.

Is this possible with NotePad++ or anything else? I'm not very familiar with regex. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Find what**: `<a href="([^"]*?\.php)">`

**Replace with**: `<a href="http://Example.com/\1">`

- I had one file opened so I clicked *'Replace All in All Opened Documents'*
- Every thing inside parentheses `()` , is captured.
- `[^"]*?` means every thing but not a `"` character. (*Lazy! stops/fails at the first occurrence.*)
- `\1` refers to the first capturing group.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `.php` files might not be formatted inside an anchor tag you can just search for the file instead of the whole `<a href ....>`

Find: `([^"]*?\.php)`

Replace: `http://Example.com/\1`

[image: find php files with regex]

Answer (score 1):

**Find**:       `(?<=")(.*?\.php)`

**Replace by**:`http://Example.com/$1`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/13

Answer (score 1):

Use look arounds:

```
Find: (?<=<a href=")(?=[^"]+\.php">)
Replace: http://Example.com/
```

This approach means not having to capture anything or use back references; it matches the insertion point for the replacement.

Comment: @revo fyi, I just ran a test (albeit in java), and replacing over 600 such hits in a 1Mb sample html file using this regex took 130ms, and for comparison using your regex took 85ms - an extra 45ms is hardly "killing" performance. Both are fast enough for a one-time editing task.

Comment: So you are talking about ~1/3 extra time in performing job by your RegEx in comparison! Yes, one time doesn't matter, you can't feel the difference and I appreciate your approach as a new look over the issue but... performance at all costs, even for 1ms is called performance. We can't overlook it.

Answer (score 0):

Select *Search Mode* as Regular expression

**Find:**  `(http://Example.com\/)`

**Replace:**  `<a href="\1dishItem.php">`

Take the cursor on first line and **Replace All**.

[image]Use following regex in notepad++